# RangeAreas by index

Tags: office-js

I'm running into performance issues with my add-in when styling many ranges. I'm trying to make some improvements by using RangeAreas. My issue is that before, I was getting ranges by indices using `Excel.Worksheet.getRangeByIndexes()`. It seems to me that `Excel.Worksheet.getRanges()` only accepts addresses. Is there an alternative using indices?

Obviously, a work around would be to convert the indices to an address, but I didn't see any standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Good! the fastest way to style will be to use the rangeAreas (formerly areas).

Unfortunately, we dont have a flavor to get the RangeAreas by Indexes, but you might do that and get the addresses and then use getRanges()

there is an interesting article who talks about all you need to know about rangeAreas: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-multiple-ranges

dont forget you can share your ideas to our team by submitting them in our uservoice channel: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Would there still be performance gains to be had considering I would have to construct all of those ranges, load their addresses, and sync before I could even get the RangeAreas?